# Create entry with Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I'm currently developing a webpage with Laravel 4.2. I've managed several problems on my own, but now I'm stuck with this. I've tried to create a new DB entry for my MySQL-Table `structures`. A connection issue can be excluded.

All connections seem to work, since all return a HTTP-Status of 200 - OK, maybe the more experienced developers of you can help me! The Namespaces are OK and all Classes are accessable. Big thanks in advance!

The **Question** is: Why does the Controller not insert any data into the Database. Am I using the wrong Controller-Function `create` or am I using it in a wrong way?

The `Structures` **Model** file in /app/models/db/Structures.php

```
namespace Database;
class Structures extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table='structures';
    protected $protected = array();
}
```

The corresponding **Controller** in /app/controllers/admin/api/StructuresController.php (Namespace Controllers\Admin\API issues can be exluded)

```
public function create($data = null)
{
    Structures::create($data)->save();
    return Response::json(array('success' => true));
}
```

I'm calling the Controller above with a `$http`-Service in **AngularJS**

```
angular.module('PagesService', [])
.factory('Structure', function($http) {
    return {
        save : function(structureData) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'admin/api/structures',
                headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                data: $.param(structureData)
            });
        }
    }
})
```

This is the corresponding Controller to the **Service**

```
angular.module('PagesController', [])
.controller('StructureController', function($scope, $http, Structure) {
    $scope.newStructure = function() {
        Structure.save({
            'title': "Änderbar",
            'type': "markdown",
            'page-id': 1,
            'order': 3,
            'class': '',
            'text': "Testtext"
        })
            .success(function(data) {
                ...
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        return false;
    }
});
```

The `routes.php` file (extract)

```
Route::resource('admin/api/structures', 'Controllers\Admin\API\StructuresController');
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Updated the entry. I'm not sure what's the problem. Am I using the Controller in a wrong way?

Comment: I don't think this is causing the problem but if you use `create()` you don't need to call `save()` it is inserted into the db automatically

Comment: Ah I think I know what it is. The post data doesn't get passed in with a function parameter. You have to do `Input::get()` to get your data

Comment: I removed `$data` from the function parameter list and replaced the parameters in `Structures::create()` to `array("key" => Input::get('value'))` but this doesn't seem to work better. Thank you.

Comment: Could you try this instead of `Structures::create()`? (just to evaluate if it is an eloquent/model problem or something else)
`DB::table('structures')->insert(array('key' => Input::get('value')))`

Comment: This is producing a 500 Internal Server Error, thus `Structures::create()` with Testdata as params `array('title' => 'test','page-id' => 1,'type' => 'text', 'order' => 3)` works pretty well.

Comment: Damn! I found the issue. `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input` was missing in the class requirements at the top -.-
I'm going to edit the whole question for users that encouter similar issues in the future. Thanks everybody!

Comment: @MartinWeise great! consider answering your own question instead of updating it instead. (You'll have to wait 8 hours to be able to accept it though). If you do that everybody can clearly see the question has been answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I found several issues that led to one big issue. As assumed, Namespaces, Database Migrations and `$http`-Services are correctly configured. Big thanks to @lukasgeiter.

The **first** issue I found was that a `$http`-Service call in **AngularJS** like:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'admin/api/structures',
    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    data: $.param(structureData)
})
```

... calls the function **store()** in my `StructureController` (please see my routes.php extract above)

The **second** issue I found was my *Model Whitelist*. I filled the `$fillable`-array() with all columns I wanted to modify.

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'page-id', 'type', 'order', 'class', 'src', 'figcaption', 'text', 'data'];
```

The **last** issue I found was, that the `create`-function can be filled with the data, given as param by the `Structure.get()` in my `PagesController` (AngularJS).

```
Structures::create(
    array(
        'title' => Input::get('title'),
        'page-id' => Input::get('page-id'),
        'type' => Input::get('type'),
        'order' => Input::get('order')
    )
);
```

**Please** be sure to include the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input` Class in at the top of the controller like:

```
namespace ...;
use ..., Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class StructuresController extends \BaseController {
...
}
```